# COPY INTO query on Snowflake returns TABLE does not exist error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to load data from azure blob storage.

The data has already been staged.

But, the issue is when I try to run

```
copy into random_table_name
from @stage_name_i_created
file_format = (type='csv')
pattern ='*.csv'
```

Below is the error I encounter:

```
raise error_class(
snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 001757 (42601): SQL compilation error:
Table 'random_table_name' does not exist
```

Basically, it says table does not exist, which it does not, but the syntax on website is the same as mine.

COPY INTO query on Snowflake returns TABLE does not exist error

Comment: What does SELECT * FROM random_table_name return

Answer (score 1):

In my case the table name is case-sensitive. Snowflake seems to convert everything to upper case. I changed the database/schema/table names to all upper-case and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

First run the below query to fetch the column headers

```
select $1  FROM @stage_name_i_created/filename.csv limit 1
```

Assuming below are the header lines from your csv file

```
   id;first_name;last_name;email;age;location
```

Create a file_format csv

```
create or replace file format semicolon
  type = 'CSV'
  field_delimiter = ';'
  skip_header=1;
```

Then you should define the datatype and field name as below

```
create or replace table <yourtable> as 
select $1::varchar  as id
,$2::varchar as first_name
,$3::varchar as last_name
,$4::varchar as email
,$5::int as age
,$6::varchar as location
FROM @stage_name_i_created/yourfile.csv  
(file_format => semicolon );
```

Answer (score 0):

The table must exist prior to running a `COPY INTO` command.  In your post, you say that the table does not exist...so that is your issue.

Comment: How do I create a table?( according to snowflake syntax it is not possible to create empty tables)

Comment: Of course you can.  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table.html

Answer (score 0):

If your table exist, try by forcing the table path like this:

```
copy into <database>.<schema>.<random_table_name>
from @stage_name_i_created
file_format = (type='csv')
pattern ='*.csv'
```

or by steps like this:

```
use database <database_name>;
use schema <schema_name>;
copy into database.schema.random_table_name
   from @stage_name_i_created
   file_format = (type='csv')
   pattern ='*.csv';
```

Answer (score 0):

rbachkaniwala, what do you mean by 'How do I create a table?( according to snowflake syntax it is not possible to create empty tables)'.

You can just do below to create a table

```
CREATE TABLE random_table_name (FIELD1 VARCHAR, FIELD2 VARCHAR)
```

Answer (score 0):

The table does need to exist. You should check the documentation for COPY INTO.
Other areas to consider are

- do you have the right context set for the database & schema
- does the user / role have access to the table or object.

It basically seems like you don't have the table defined yet. You should

- ensure the table is created
- ensure all columns in the CSV exist as columns in the table
- ensure the order of the columns are the same as in the CSV
- I'd check data types too.

Answer (score 0):

`"COPY INTO"` is not a query command, it is the actual data transfer execution from source to destination, which both must exist as others commented here but If you want just to query without loading the files then run the following SQL:

```
//Display list of files in the stage to verify stage

LIST @stage_name_i_created; 

//Create a file format 

CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT RANDOM_FILE_CSV 
type = csv
COMPRESSION = 'GZIP' FIELD_DELIMITER = ',' RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n' SKIP_HEADER = 0 FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '\042' 
TRIM_SPACE = FALSE ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = FALSE ESCAPE = 'NONE' ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = 'NONE' DATE_FORMAT = 'AUTO' TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'AUTO' 
NULL_IF = ('\\N'); 


//Now select the data in the files
 
Select $1 as first_col,$2 as second_col  //can add as necessary number of columns ...etc
from @stage_name_i_created

(FILE_FORMAT => RANDOM_FILE_CSV)
```

More information can be found in the documentation link here
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-stage.html